# Share map with own points?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

do you know about some map provider, where "admin" can insert some points of interest (with description of points), and then share the map with other people so they can easily (via internet browser) find which map point is the closest to their location?

For example I'd like to insert (or import addreses) all pubs in our region, and then share the map with my friends? And they will find their location and will see the closest pubs in their neighbourhood?

The best would be, if they can even set some range (e.g. 20 miles) and the map will focus on the pubs in specified range.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Google. Log in to your Google account and go to maps.google.com. Then click on "My Places" at top left and "Create Map" so you can add points. [Here](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=201563723600331406781.000001135816b2ac74796&msa=0) is one I have made.